# Canvas transparency mask effect reset

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to overlay a canvas on a page in an attempt to make it look like it has been frosted over and then use mousemove to clear it away, following this post:

http://www.stevecalderon.com/2012/03/html5-canvas-tricks-transparency-mask-for-eraser-effect.html

I have created a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZWsG6/2/

```
var canvas = "";
var ctx = "";

function frost2(){

var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);

canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
var objTo = document.getElementById("fltouch");
objTo.appendChild(canvas);

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.95;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';    

function drawPoint(pointX,pointY){

    ///scrape
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(pointX - 75,pointY-5,pointX + 75,pointY + 5)

grd.addColorStop(0, "transparent"); 
grd.addColorStop(0.3, "rgba(255,255,255,.6)"); 
grd.addColorStop(0.7, "rgba(255,255,255,.6)"); 
grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent"); 

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(pointX - 75,pointY,400,30);

    }

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            drawPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY);
        },false);

}


function clock(){
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.95;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';    

}
```

I've added a function clock() to run every second and refill the canvas with the colour so that it needs to be cleared again but it doesn't work, only remove the fill altogether.

Can anyone please tell how to reset the canvas to be filled with colour again? If it could be done slowly to look sorta like it is freezing over again that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `globalCompositeOperation` back to default `source-over` value before refilling a canvas:

```
function clock() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.95;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqCbv/1/

Comment: thankyou, I should've paid more attention to that property and what it does

Comment: I know this is old but Instead of resetting the canvas in clock() is there a way to detect what percentage has been cleared. So we can trigger a function when say more than 75% has been cleared. Thanks in advance